# How to Convert two 8 bit represented byte to single 16 bit represented integer value in Android

Tags: java, android

I have an Android application with the BLE module. the BLE device is giving byte array with 24 bytes. Each byte has a separate meaning. In the byte array, 10 and 11 items are voltage and its a combination of 16-bit representation.

eg: I am getting the 11 item as 0 and 12 item as 3. So I want to convert it to a single 16-bit representation value. Also, I want to get this as a float value, because I need to display the voltage as a float value in the UI. I don't know anyone already ask this question. If anyone know the formulae for 8 bit to 16-bit representation please add the formulae.

Comment: Is it in a scope smaller than 1V for example mV? If not then you can just add ",0" for display ... Is Byte 11 or 12 the least significant for the 16bit value? i.e. #11=0 , #12=3 => "03" or "30" ?

Comment: what about negative numbers. I am getting negative number also.

Comment: You should ask a  new Question referring to this one for this.

Comment: Please check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38118276/android-8-bit-to-16-bit-representation-for-negative-numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this it may help you

```
short yourinteger16 = (short)(((bytes[0] & 0xFF) << 8) | (bytes[1] & 0xFF));
```

Comment: This is working fine for positive numbers. But in the case of negative numbers, it's making wrong value. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
short yourinteger16 = ((short) ((bytes[0] & 0xff) | (bytes[1] << 8)));
```

-TESTED-
This is the general form for both positive and negative numbers