# Android 8 bit to 16 bit representation for Negative Numbers

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Refer to the question [How to Convert two 8 bit represented byte to single 16 bit represented integer value in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37831108/how-to-convert-two-8-bit-represented-byte-to-single-16-bit-represented-integer-v?noredirect=1#comment63667151_37831108). 
I got an answer like this

```
short yourinteger16 = (short)(((bytes[0] & 0xFF) << 8) | (bytes[1] & 0xFF));
```

This answer is correct for the positive number. But in the case of the negative number, it's failing.

For example,  I am sending the value from the BLE to the application as -10. The value will convert from the BLE as -10000 because of mAh/mV conversion of current and voltage. These values are split into two bytes and I am getting the byte value as -39 and -16 in my application. I am passing the byte to the method as like below.

```
short yourinteger16 = (short)(((-39 & 0xFF) << 8) | (-16 & 0xFF));
```

But I am getting the result as 9.77 as the float value of yourinteger16 .

Anyone has any idea about this?. Any solution please update me.

Full Code:

```
Integer ampValue = null;
        if (mBleDataHashMap.containsKey(SuperMuttBleConst.RESP_I_HIGH) &&
                mBleDataHashMap.containsKey(SuperMuttBleConst.RESP_I_LOW)) {
            ampValue = get8ByteTo16Byte(mBleDataHashMap.get(SuperMuttBleConst.RESP_I_HIGH),
                    mBleDataHashMap.get(SuperMuttBleConst.RESP_I_LOW));

        }
        if (ampValue != null) {
            float newAmp = ampValue.floatValue();
            newAmp = newAmp/1000;
            mAmpTextvw.setText("" + newAmp);
        }
```

Method

```
 protected Integer get8ByteTo16Byte(int firstValue, int secondValue) {
        Short integerValue =  (short)((((byte) firstValue & 0xFF) << 8) | ((byte) secondValue & 0xFF));
        return new Integer(integerValue);
    }
```

Comment: How do you create the float? What is the resulting short value?

Comment: Integer integerValue =  ((((byte) firstValue & 0xFF) << 8) | ((byte) secondValue & 0xFF));
float newAmp = integerValue .floatValue();

Comment: Ah, wait a minute ... Is that Hex -39 or Dec -39 ?

Comment: Any calculation mistake in Integer to float conversion?

Comment: I am getting the values as two bytes from the BLE device as -39 and -16

Comment: Can you post the whole function of your code?

Comment: yes sure. will edit the question soon. One thing I want to update is the data will multiply with 1000 from the BLE. So the result value is -10*1000. This is because of unit conversion. Ah to mAh and V to mV.

Comment: Please evaluate the edited question

Comment: Yes, its 9.77. It's my Typo error. The value is 9.77. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're receiving -39 and -16 *perfectly* (the high and low bytes for -10000, respectively).

Use `addition` instead of `OR`ing the high and low bytes.
Please try the following

```
    short result = (short) (((short)(-39 & (byte)0xFF) << 8) + (short)(-16 & (byte)0xFF));
```

The negative low bytes is causing trouble for the high byte when dealing with 2's complement arithmetic.

Comment: Yes, now the negative value is getting as -10. But How can we create a generalized method for both positive and negative value? It may dynamically change from BLE. We can't predict the value. Now the positive value is making issue.

Comment: You mean... -10000?

I tried with all combinations:

    `-39 and -16 yields -10000`
    39 and 16 yields 10000
    `-39 and 16 yields -9968`
    39 and -16 yields 9968.

I don't see any exceptions. Which is the combination not working for you?

Comment: Yes, your answer is correct for Positive values also. Thanks,  Sahil Bajaj.

Comment: But what about the fractional number? This may make an error right?

Comment: Any solution for the fractional numbers?